# press enter via python script

Tags: python, pywin32

We are trying to create a python script to install an app via windows shell prompt, executing our python script. We have an output prompt from the app.exe indicating
"Press Enter to Continue..."

We tried to simulate the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but it doesn't work. The prompt just sits still not moving to the next wizard step.

How do we overcome this problem?

```
import subprocess
import win32console

APP_BIN = 'app.exe'

def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen([APP_BIN,'-i','console'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.stdin.write("\r\n")            <--- issue
    output = proc.stdout.readline()     <--- issue
    print output
    ret = proc.wait()
    print ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `proc.stdin` is likely buffered.  If it is you will need to do `proc.stdin.flush()` to make sure the process has recieved all the characters you have sent.  I don't know if that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure how to do it in python, but my suggestion would be simulate an actual 'enter' key press command. In your code, you are just changing caret's position and not issuing a proper return.

Have a look at this: http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/136/254/

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
```

Seems like that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Add a small code example and it'll be a +1 from me, just in case the link dies.

Comment: Hi Zorle thankd for the response; i tried and still has the same effect, no catching the Enter key

Comment: Try to test it on a normal console window. See if you can use this code to inject letters and other things into it. If not, keep trying until you get it to a stage when you can. Then it should be easy to transfer across to your actual script.

Answer (score 0):

The following may work (untested):

```
import subprocess
import win32console

APP_BIN = 'app.exe'

def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen([APP_BIN,'-i','console'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate(input="\r\n")
    output = stdoutdata.readline()
    print output
    ret = proc.wait()
    print ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Martineau thanks for the response. It doesnt work - still the same effect; didnt see the enter key entering to push to the next wizard step.

Comment: To bad. It's possible the app isn't reading stdin, in which case you'll probably need to use one the other PyWin32 modules to do what you want. Try Googling `windows simulate keyboard input`. There's something called [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html) that might work for console apps, too.

Comment: Hi martineau thanks for responding. We're still struggling to get it to work.